# Download images using web browser control

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

In my web browser app for windows phone 7, am able to just see the images, but i want to download images from the web pages(using context menu) and save it to media library. My web browser control is named as **browsers**. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance for your help? 
There are errors in the below codes- In **"uri"** and in **"e"**.

```
private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        HttpWebRequest WebRequest = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(uri);>>>Error in "uri"
        WebRequest.BeginGetResponse((asyncCallback) =>
        {
            try
            {
                MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary();
                library.SavePicture(imageName, WebRequest.EndGetResponse(asyncCallback).GetResponseStream());
            }
            catch (Exception e)>>>>>Error in "e"
            {}
        }, WebRequest); 
    }

public string imageName { get; set; }
```

Comment: I dont know what to do, am just able to do the above for mp3 and pdf files. Please check my edited post!

Comment: I dont know how to use this codes for waeb page to download an image from web page and to save it media library?
private void PicToMediaLibary(Stream pic) {
     MediaLibrary lib = new MediaLibrary();
     lib.SavePicture("blah", pic);
}

Comment: @Ku6opr Do you have any samples for HttpWebRequest?

Answer (score 0):

Tab and hold on the image in the Browser control ... DO you geta  context menu for saving the Image ?

Comment: No, not getting any context menu for anything!

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpWebRequest WebRequest = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(uri);
WebRequest.BeginGetResponse((asyncCallback) =>
{
    try
    {            
        MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary();
        library.SavePicture(imageName, WebRequest.EndGetResponse(asyncCallback).GetResponseStream());
    }
    catch (Exception e) { }
}, WebRequest);
```

Comment: `uri` is your Uri, you need to assign it before

Comment: Is this correct?--->HttpWebRequest WebRequest = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(new Uri(UrlTextBox.Text, UriKind.Absolute));

Comment: I used context menu to do the above but it didn't work. Did you test your codes?